# non-polynomial functions on fields of finite characteristic

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102754/clarification-on-taylors-formula) raised another question in my mind.  In finite fields $F$, every function from $F$ to itself is a polynomial.  What about infinite fields of finite (i.e. non-zero) characteristic?  Are there non-polynomial functions there?

---- Naively

Comment: Sure, non-polynomial is any function $\ne 0$ with infinitely many roots, e.g. delta functions, step functions, etc.

Answer (score 9):

If a field is infinite, of whatever characteristic, the function that takes value $1$ on $0$ and $0$ on $x\neq0$ is not polynomial.

Answer (score 9):

If a field $F$ has infinite cardinality $\kappa$, then there are $\kappa^\kappa=2^\kappa$ functions from $F$ to $F$, but only $\kappa$ polynomials over $F$. Since $2^\kappa > \kappa$, there must be non-polynomial functions.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this one. If your whole answer had been just one word, "cardinality", I'd have had it in an instant.  Haste makes waste.

Answer (score 2):

The full story about polynomials versus polynomial functions over an integral domain is told in $\S 14.1$ of [my undergraduate number theory notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400FULL.pdf).  (In particular you will find both Andrea's and Chris's answers in there.)

Comment: Unable to access your notes attached your comment.